# lxml : while loop with node same elements

Tags: python, while-loop, lxml

I'm using lxml to create a json file based on a xml. The xml file has this kind of structure :

```
<spots_list>
    <spot id="001" latitude="2011464" longitude="979511">
        <adress>Somewhere</adress>
        <city>BOSTON</city>
        <price category="Intermediate" value="782"/>
        <price category="Expensive" value="2765"/>
        <price category="Cheap" value="12"/>
     </spot>
    <spot id="002" latitude="2101644" longitude="915971">
        <adress>Somewhere else (very very far away)</adress>
        <city>CAMBRIDGE</city>
        <price category="Intermediate" value="472"/>
        <price category="Intermediate (but less expensive)" value="422"/>
        <price category="Expensive" value="20275"/>
        <price category="Cheap" value="12"/>
     </spot>
</spots_list>
```

The number of price elements in every  can change, so I tried to use a while loop in Python. Here's the associate code :

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse("my_file.xml")

for node in tree.xpath("//spots_list/spot"):
    for adress in node.xpath("adress"):
        adr = adress.text
    while node.xpath("price"):
        print(adr)
```

I know it's wrong, because the first adress appears over and over, but I don't figure how formulate this loop to switch for next  elements...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic problem in the `while` statement is that `node.xpath(...)` returns a list, which is considered `True` if it is not empty. You just have to do the same thing as at the top level, i.e. iterate over the elements you are interested in, e.g.

```
def parse_spot(el):
    adr = el.find('adress')
    return dict(
        address=adr.text if adr is not None else None,  # error handling if not found
        price=[dict(p.attrib) for p in el.findall('price')]
    )

tree = etree.fromstring(xml)  # xml is your example as string

[parse_spot(el) for el in tree.findall('./spot')]
```

You can also use `xpath` instead of `findall` like you did.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer !